# Java Swing GridBagLayout JTextField Changing size after adding error message

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have been chasing this bug for awhile and can't seem to figure it out. I have a small GUI with a list of labels and text fields. In between the rows that have a label + text field, there is an empty row that contains a JLabel to populate with an error message as necessary. The issue is, when this error message populates, the text fields above them are compressed for some reason and after a few hours of trying different things, I can't seem to pinpoint why. It also seems like all the labels/text areas compress compared to each other slightly as well. Can anyone point out the issue?

I have tried giving each element more space as well in the panel gridbaglayout. That doesn't seem to change the end result.

If looking at the code, the elements are on the 'continuousTransferPanel" Also the "singleTransferPanel" has the same issue with only 2 rows.

[image: No Error Messages]

[image: Error Messages]

```
 public void modifyJobWindow()
{
    setTitle("Job Editor");

    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(350, 400));
    this.setSize(350, 300);
    this.setResizable(false);

    JPanel basePanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(basePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    basePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    basePanel.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(49, 49, 47));
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel optionPanel = new JPanel();
    optionPanel.setBackground(new Color(49, 49, 47));
    mainPanel.add(optionPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel transferLabel = new JLabel("Transfer Type: ");
    transferLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    transferLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
    transferLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    optionPanel.add(transferLabel);

    comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Single File Transfer"))
            {
                acceptButton.setEnabled(true);
                continuousTransferPanel.setVisible(false);
                deleteSourceCheckBox.setSelected(false);
                deleteSourceCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                deleteSourceCheckBox.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                autostartCheckBox.setSelected(false);
                autostartCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
                autostartCheckBox.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
                singleTransferPanel.setVisible(true);
                clearErrors();
            }
            else if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Continuous File Transfer"))
            {
                acceptButton.setEnabled(true);
                deleteSourceCheckBox.setSelected(false);
                deleteSourceCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                deleteSourceCheckBox.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                singleTransferPanel.setVisible(false);
                autostartCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                autostartCheckBox.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                continuousTransferPanel.setVisible(true);
                clearErrors();
            }
            else
            {
                acceptButton.setEnabled(false);
                deleteSourceCheckBox.setSelected(false);
                deleteSourceCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
                deleteSourceCheckBox.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
                autostartCheckBox.setSelected(false);
                autostartCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
                autostartCheckBox.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
                singleTransferPanel.setVisible(false);
                continuousTransferPanel.setVisible(false);
                clearErrors();
            }
        }
    });
    comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"", "Single File Transfer", "Continuous File Transfer"}));
    comboBox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
    optionPanel.add(comboBox);

    JPanel subMainPanel = new JPanel();
    subMainPanel.setBackground(new Color(49, 49, 47));
    mainPanel.add(subMainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    GridBagLayout gbl_subMainpanel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_subMainpanel.columnWidths = new int[] {400};
    gbl_subMainpanel.rowHeights = new int[] {175};
    gbl_subMainpanel.columnWeights = new double[] {1.0};
    gbl_subMainpanel.rowWeights = new double[] {0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    subMainPanel.setLayout(gbl_subMainpanel);

    continuousTransferPanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_continuousTransferPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_continuousTransferPanel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_continuousTransferPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_continuousTransferPanel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_continuousTransferPanel.gridy = 0;
    subMainPanel.add(continuousTransferPanel, gbc_continuousTransferPanel);
    continuousTransferPanel.setBackground(new Color(49, 49, 47));
    GridBagLayout gbl_continuousTransferPanel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_continuousTransferPanel.columnWidths = new int[] {100, 300};
    gbl_continuousTransferPanel.rowHeights = new int[] {25, 15, 25, 15, 25, 15, 25, 15};
    gbl_continuousTransferPanel.columnWeights = new double[] {0.0, 1.0};
    gbl_continuousTransferPanel.rowWeights = new double[] {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    continuousTransferPanel.setLayout(gbl_continuousTransferPanel);
    continuousTransferPanel.setVisible(false);

    JLabel jobCNameLabel = new JLabel("Job Name:");
    jobCNameLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
    jobCNameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_jobCNameLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_jobCNameLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_jobCNameLabel.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_jobCNameLabel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_jobCNameLabel.gridy = 0;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(jobCNameLabel, gbc_jobCNameLabel);

    JLabel sourceCLabel = new JLabel("Source Folder:");
    sourceCLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
    sourceCLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_sourceCLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_sourceCLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_sourceCLabel.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_sourceCLabel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_sourceCLabel.gridy = 2;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(sourceCLabel, gbc_sourceCLabel);

    JLabel destCLabel = new JLabel("Destination:");
    destCLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    destCLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_destCLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_destCLabel.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_destCLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_destCLabel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_destCLabel.gridy = 4;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(destCLabel, gbc_destCLabel);

    JLabel fileFilterLabel = new JLabel("File Regex:");
    fileFilterLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    fileFilterLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_fileFilterLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_fileFilterLabel.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_fileFilterLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_fileFilterLabel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_fileFilterLabel.gridy = 6;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(fileFilterLabel, gbc_fileFilterLabel);

    jobCNameField = new JTextField();
    jobCNameField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_jobCNameField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_jobCNameField.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_jobCNameField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_jobCNameField.gridx = 1;
    gbc_jobCNameField.gridy = 0;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(jobCNameField, gbc_jobCNameField);

    errorFieldCJobName = new JLabel("");
    errorFieldCJobName.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 8));
    errorFieldCJobName.setForeground(Color.RED);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_errorFieldCJobName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_errorFieldCJobName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_errorFieldCJobName.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_errorFieldCJobName.gridx = 1;
    gbc_errorFieldCJobName.gridy = 1;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(errorFieldCJobName, gbc_errorFieldCJobName);

    sourceCField = new JTextField();
    sourceCField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_sourceCField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_sourceCField.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_sourceCField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_sourceCField.gridx = 1;
    gbc_sourceCField.gridy = 2;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(sourceCField, gbc_sourceCField);

    errorFieldCSourceField = new JLabel("");
    errorFieldCSourceField.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 8));
    errorFieldCSourceField.setForeground(Color.RED);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_errorFieldCSourceField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_errorFieldCSourceField.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_errorFieldCSourceField.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_errorFieldCSourceField.gridx = 1;
    gbc_errorFieldCSourceField.gridy = 3;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(errorFieldCSourceField, gbc_errorFieldCSourceField);

    destCField = new JTextField();
    destCField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_destCField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_destCField.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_destCField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_destCField.gridx = 1;
    gbc_destCField.gridy = 4;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(destCField, gbc_destCField);

    errorFieldCDest = new JLabel("");
    errorFieldCDest.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 8));
    errorFieldCDest.setForeground(Color.RED);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_errorFieldCDest = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_errorFieldCDest.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_errorFieldCDest.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_errorFieldCDest.gridx = 1;
    gbc_errorFieldCDest.gridy = 5;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(errorFieldCDest, gbc_errorFieldCDest);

    fileFilterField = new JTextField();
    fileFilterField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_fileFilterField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_fileFilterField.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_fileFilterField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_fileFilterField.gridx = 1;
    gbc_fileFilterField.gridy = 6;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(fileFilterField, gbc_fileFilterField);

    errorFieldFileRegex = new JLabel("");
    errorFieldFileRegex.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 8));
    errorFieldFileRegex.setForeground(Color.RED);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_errorFieldFileRegex = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_errorFieldFileRegex.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_errorFieldFileRegex.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_errorFieldFileRegex.gridx = 1;
    gbc_errorFieldFileRegex.gridy = 7;
    continuousTransferPanel.add(errorFieldFileRegex, gbc_errorFieldFileRegex);

    singleTransferPanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_singleTransferPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_singleTransferPanel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_singleTransferPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_singleTransferPanel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_singleTransferPanel.gridy = 0;
    subMainPanel.add(singleTransferPanel, gbc_singleTransferPanel);
    singleTransferPanel.setBackground(new Color(49, 49, 47));
    GridBagLayout gbl_singleTransferPanel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_singleTransferPanel.columnWidths = new int[] {100, 200};
    gbl_singleTransferPanel.rowHeights = new int[] {30, 15, 30, 15};
    gbl_singleTransferPanel.columnWeights = new double[] {0.0, 1.0};
    gbl_singleTransferPanel.rowWeights = new double[] {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    singleTransferPanel.setLayout(gbl_singleTransferPanel);
    singleTransferPanel.setVisible(false);

    JLabel sourceLabel = new JLabel("Source File:");
    sourceLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
    sourceLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_sourceLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_sourceLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_sourceLabel.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_sourceLabel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_sourceLabel.gridy = 0;
    singleTransferPanel.add(sourceLabel, gbc_sourceLabel);

    JLabel destLabel = new JLabel("Destination:");
    destLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    destLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_destLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_destLabel.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_destLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_destLabel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_destLabel.gridy = 2;
    singleTransferPanel.add(destLabel, gbc_destLabel);

    sourceField = new JTextField();
    sourceField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_sourceField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_sourceField.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_sourceField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_sourceField.gridx = 1;
    gbc_sourceField.gridy = 0;
    singleTransferPanel.add(sourceField, gbc_sourceField);

    errorFieldSourceField = new JLabel("");
    errorFieldSourceField.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 8));
    errorFieldSourceField.setForeground(Color.RED);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_errorFieldSourceField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_errorFieldSourceField.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_errorFieldSourceField.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_errorFieldSourceField.gridx = 1;
    gbc_errorFieldSourceField.gridy = 1;
    singleTransferPanel.add(errorFieldSourceField, gbc_errorFieldSourceField);

    destField = new JTextField();
    destField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_destField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_destField.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_destField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_destField.gridx = 1;
    gbc_destField.gridy = 2;
    singleTransferPanel.add(destField, gbc_destField);

    errorFieldDest = new JLabel("");
    errorFieldDest.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 8));
    errorFieldDest.setForeground(Color.RED);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_errorFieldDest = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_errorFieldDest.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_errorFieldDest.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5);
    gbc_errorFieldDest.gridx = 1;
    gbc_errorFieldDest.gridy = 3;
    singleTransferPanel.add(errorFieldDest, gbc_errorFieldDest);

    JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
    basePanel.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    titlePanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));
    titlePanel.setBackground(new Color(49, 49, 47));
    titlePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));

    JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("File Transfer Job Editor");
    titleLabel.setForeground(new Color(243, 112, 33));
    titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 28));
    titlePanel.add(titleLabel);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    basePanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    buttonPanel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    GridBagLayout gbl_buttonPanel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_buttonPanel.columnWidths = new int[] {175, 175, 0};
    gbl_buttonPanel.rowHeights = new int[] {30, 30, 0};
    gbl_buttonPanel.columnWeights = new double[] {1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_buttonPanel.rowWeights = new double[] {0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    buttonPanel.setBackground(new Color(49, 49, 47));
    buttonPanel.setLayout(gbl_buttonPanel);

    autostartCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Auto Start");
    autostartCheckBox.setForeground(Color.gray);
    autostartCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
    autostartCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    autostartCheckBox.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 16));
    autostartCheckBox.setBackground(new Color(49, 49, 47));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_autostartCheckBox = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_autostartCheckBox.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc_autostartCheckBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc_autostartCheckBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_autostartCheckBox.gridx = 0;
    gbc_autostartCheckBox.gridy = 0;
    buttonPanel.add(autostartCheckBox, gbc_autostartCheckBox);

    deleteSourceCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Delete Source File");
    deleteSourceCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    deleteSourceCheckBox.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    deleteSourceCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
    deleteSourceCheckBox.setForeground(Color.gray);
    deleteSourceCheckBox.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 16));
    deleteSourceCheckBox.setBackground(new Color(49, 49, 47));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_deleteSourceCheckBox = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_deleteSourceCheckBox.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc_deleteSourceCheckBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc_deleteSourceCheckBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_deleteSourceCheckBox.gridx = 1;
    gbc_deleteSourceCheckBox.gridy = 0;
    buttonPanel.add(deleteSourceCheckBox, gbc_deleteSourceCheckBox);

    JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            close();
        }
    });
    cancelButton.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 14));
    cancelButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_generateButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_generateButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 0);
    gbc_generateButton.gridx = 0;
    gbc_generateButton.gridy = 1;
    buttonPanel.add(cancelButton, gbc_generateButton);

    acceptButton = new JButton("Accept");
    acceptButton.setEnabled(false);
    acceptButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            success = true;
            if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Single File Transfer"))
            {

                if (sourceField.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    File sourceCheck = new File(sourceField.getText());
                    if (sourceCheck.exists() && sourceCheck.isFile())
                    {
                        // Success
                        sourceField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                        errorFieldSourceField.setText("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sourceField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                        errorFieldSourceField.setText("File does not exist.");
                        success = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sourceField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                    errorFieldSourceField.setText("Cannot be empty.");
                    success = false;
                }

                if (destField.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    destField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                    errorFieldDest.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    destField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                    errorFieldDest.setText("Cannot be empty.");
                    success = false;
                }

                if (success == true)
                {
                    Job newJob = new Job("SingleJob", sourceField.getText(), destField.getText(), null, deleteSourceCheckBox.isSelected(), true);
                    // TODO: Start Job
                }

            }
            else if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Continuous File Transfer"))
            {
                success = true;

                if (jobCNameField.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    File jobNameCheck = new File("jobs/" + jobCNameField.getText() + ".job");
                    if (jobNameCheck.exists() && modify == false)
                    {
                        jobCNameField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                        errorFieldCJobName.setText("Job name already exists.");
                        success = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Success
                        jobCNameField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                        errorFieldCJobName.setText("");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    jobCNameField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                    errorFieldCJobName.setText("Cannot be empty.");
                    success = false;
                }

                if (sourceCField.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    File sourceCheck = new File(sourceCField.getText());
                    if (sourceCheck.exists() && sourceCheck.isDirectory())
                    {
                        // Success
                        sourceCField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                        errorFieldCSourceField.setText("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sourceCField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                        errorFieldCSourceField.setText("Directory does not exist.");
                        success = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sourceCField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                    errorFieldCSourceField.setText("Cannot be empty.");
                    success = false;
                }

                if (destCField.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    destCField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                    errorFieldCDest.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    destCField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                    errorFieldCDest.setText("Cannot be empty.");
                    success = false;
                }

                try
                {
                    Pattern.compile(fileFilterField.getText());
                    errorFieldFileRegex.setText("");
                    fileFilterField.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                }
                catch (PatternSyntaxException exception)
                {
                    fileFilterField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                    errorFieldFileRegex.setText("Invalid syntax.");
                    success = false;
                }

                if (success == true)
                {
                    if (modify)
                    {
                        FileTransferUtility.jobList.remove(originalJob);
                        FileTransferGUI.clearJobFromTable(originalJob);
                        // TODO: Stop if running
                    }

                    if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Continuous File Transfer"))
                    {
                        Job newJob = new Job(jobCNameField.getText(), sourceCField.getText(), destCField.getText(), fileFilterField.getText(), deleteSourceCheckBox.isSelected(),
                                autostartCheckBox.isSelected());
                        JobHandler newJobHandler = new JobHandler(newJob);
                        FileTransferUtility.jobList.add(newJobHandler);
                        newJob.writeToFile("/jobs");
                        FileTransferGUI.addJobToTable(newJobHandler);
                        if (autostartCheckBox.isSelected())
                        {
                            // TODO: Start Job
                        }
                    }
                    close();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    acceptButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    acceptButton.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 14));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_closeButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_closeButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 0);
    gbc_closeButton.gridx = 1;
    gbc_closeButton.gridy = 1;
    buttonPanel.add(acceptButton, gbc_closeButton);

    JPanel entryPanel = new JPanel();
    entryPanel.setBorder(null);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Try creating the JLabel with a " " instead of the empty string. This should allow the layout to calculate the proper height for the label.

Comment: I tried that already (and just re-tried just in case) and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: A valid [mcve] would help reduce the work load of those wanting to answer

Comment: I don't know why you are using all those rowHeights and columnWidths. Swing components should determine their own preferred size. Let the layout manger do the work. Also, when you create the text fields you should use something like `new JTextField(10)` so the text field can size itself to display 10 "W" characters. Post an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem if you need more help. So you only need the code for one panel that demonstrates the problem. We should be able to compile the code.

Comment: You could also greatly simplify and abbreviate that code by using arrays or ArrayLists along with a for loop. This makes debugging, enhancing and changing much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem is with your JTextField's Border, and since you can't reset the default border outright without running into problems, one solution is to create a CompoundBorder for your JTextField, the outer border a LineBorder that uses the same color as the JPanel's background color and the inner border being JTextField's default border. Then in your action listener, simply create a new compound border, one that uses a Color.RED outer border.

So when creating my JTextFields in the example below, I also create a CompoundBorder, giving it an outerBorder and innerBorder like so:

```
// create JTextField with TF_COLS int column count value
JTextField textField = new JTextField(TF_COLS);

// get the JTextField's default border and make it our inner border
Border innerBorder = textField.getBorder();

// create an outer LineBorder that uses the JPanel's background color
Border outerBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(BACKGROUND);

// create the compound border with these two borders
CompoundBorder myBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outerBorder, innerBorder);

// and set the JTextField's border with it
textField.setBorder(myBorder);
```

Then in the JButton's ActionListener, get the JTextField's current border, **our compound border**, and change the outer border's line color. Simple:

```
// loop through all the JLabel texts
for (int i = 0; i < LABELS.length; i++) {
    String text = LABELS[i];  // get the array item

    // use it to get the JTextField associated with this String
    JTextField textField = labelFieldMap.get(text);
    // same for the error JLabel
    JLabel errorLabel = errorLabelMap.get(text);

    // get our current JTextField's border which is a compound border
    CompoundBorder myBorder = (CompoundBorder) textField.getBorder();

    // the insideBorder, the original JTextField's border, will be unchanged
    Border insideBorder = myBorder.getInsideBorder();

    // if the text field is empty (and not the last jtext field)
    if (i < LABELS.length - 1 && textField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
        errorLabel.setText(ERROR_MESSAGE);  // set the error JLabel

        // set txt field's color if we want
        textField.setBackground(ERROR_BG_COLOR); 

        // okToTransfer = false;

        // create a compound border, the outer border now a line border, RED
        Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED);
        CompoundBorder newBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder, insideBorder);

        // set the JTextField's border to this one
        textField.setBorder(newBorder);
    } else {
        // else all OK
        errorLabel.setText(" ");
        textField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        // set the JTextField's border back to our original compound border
        Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(BACKGROUND);
        CompoundBorder newBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder,
                insideBorder);
        textField.setBorder(newBorder);
    }
    System.out.println(text + " " + textField.getText());
}
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String[] LABELS = { "Job Name:", "Source Folder:", "Destination:",
            "File Regex:" };
    private static final int TF_COLS = 30;
    private static final Font LABEL_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 12);
    private static final Font ERROR_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 8);
    private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "Cannot Be Empty";
    private static final Color BACKGROUND = new Color(49, 49, 47);
    private static final String TITLE = "File Transfer Job Editor";
    private static final Color TITLE_COLOR = new Color(243, 112, 33);
    private static final Font TITLE_FONT = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 28);
    private static final Color ERROR_BG_COLOR = new Color(255, 220, 220);
    private Map<String, JTextField> labelFieldMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, JLabel> errorLabelMap = new HashMap<>();

    public MyPanel() {
        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(TITLE, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        titleLabel.setForeground(TITLE_COLOR);
        titleLabel.setFont(TITLE_FONT);

        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
        titlePanel.setOpaque(false);
        titlePanel.add(titleLabel);
        titlePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        JPanel labelFieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        labelFieldPanel.setOpaque(false);
        int bGap = 3;
        labelFieldPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(bGap, bGap, bGap, bGap));

        for (int i = 0; i < LABELS.length; i++) {
            String text = LABELS[i];
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            JTextField textField = new JTextField(TF_COLS);
            JLabel errorLabel = new JLabel("    ");
            Border innerBorder = textField.getBorder();
            Border outerBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(BACKGROUND);
            CompoundBorder myBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outerBorder, innerBorder);
            textField.setBorder(myBorder);

            label.setFont(LABEL_FONT);
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            errorLabel.setFont(ERROR_FONT);
            errorLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);

            labelFieldMap.put(text, textField);
            errorLabelMap.put(text, errorLabel);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = createLabelConstraint(i);
            labelFieldPanel.add(label, gbc);

            gbc = createTextFieldConstraints(i);
            labelFieldPanel.add(textField, gbc);

            gbc = createErrorLabelConstraints(i);
            labelFieldPanel.add(errorLabel, gbc);

            // add blank JLabel at the 0 position
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            labelFieldPanel.add(new JLabel(), gbc);
        }

        JButton acceptButton = new JButton("Accept");
        acceptButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        acceptButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            boolean okToTransfer = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < LABELS.length; i++) {
                String text = LABELS[i];
                JTextField textField = labelFieldMap.get(text);
                JLabel errorLabel = errorLabelMap.get(text);

                CompoundBorder myBorder = (CompoundBorder) textField.getBorder();
                Border insideBorder = myBorder.getInsideBorder();

                if (i < LABELS.length - 1 && textField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    errorLabel.setText(ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    textField.setBackground(ERROR_BG_COLOR);
                    okToTransfer = false;
                    Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED);
                    CompoundBorder newBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder, insideBorder);
                    textField.setBorder(newBorder);
                } else {
                    errorLabel.setText(" ");
                    textField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(BACKGROUND);
                    CompoundBorder newBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder, insideBorder);
                    textField.setBorder(newBorder);
                }
                System.out.println(text + " " + textField.getText());
            }
            System.out.println();
            if (okToTransfer) {
                // TODO: transfer code here
                // Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MyPanel.this);
                // win.dispose();
            }
        });
        JButton cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        cancelBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MyPanel.this);
            win.dispose();
        });
        int btnPanelGap = 15;
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, btnPanelGap, 0));
        btnPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, btnPanelGap, 4, btnPanelGap));
        btnPanel.setOpaque(false);
        btnPanel.add(acceptButton);
        btnPanel.add(cancelBtn);

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        setBackground(BACKGROUND);
        add(titlePanel);
        add(labelFieldPanel);
        add(btnPanel);
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createErrorLabelConstraints(int i) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2 * i + 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        return gbc;
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createTextFieldConstraints(int i) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2 * i;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        return gbc;
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createLabelConstraint(int i) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2 * i;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        return gbc;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyPanel mainPanel = new MyPanel();

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog((JFrame) null, "Job Editor", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: @Tacitus86: you're welcome, it was an interesting project. But also, please note how I created a [mcve] to test and solve. In the future if you post more questions, please consider doing something similar with your question code. Also I can't stress enough the benefits of avoiding duplication with arrays and collections (here Maps based on the JLabel text).

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but I cannot reproduce your problem with my attempt at an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Note the use of arrays and collections (here maps) to simplify the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String[] LABELS = {"Job Name:", "Source Folder:", "Destination:", "File Regex:"};
    private static final int TF_COLS = 20;
    private static final Font LABEL_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 12);
    private static final Font ERROR_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 8);
    private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "Cannot Be Empty";
    private static final Color BACKGROUND = new Color(49, 49, 47);
    private Map<String, JTextField> labelFieldMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, JLabel> errorLabelMap = new HashMap<>();

    public MyPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(BACKGROUND);

        JPanel labelFieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        labelFieldPanel.setOpaque(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < LABELS.length; i++) {
            String text = LABELS[i];
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            JTextField textField = new JTextField(TF_COLS);
            JLabel errorLabel = new JLabel("    ");

            label.setFont(LABEL_FONT);
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            errorLabel.setFont(ERROR_FONT);
            errorLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);


            labelFieldMap.put(text, textField);
            errorLabelMap.put(text, errorLabel);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = createLabelConstraint(i);
            labelFieldPanel.add(label, gbc);

            gbc = createTextFieldConstraints(i);
            labelFieldPanel.add(textField, gbc);

            gbc = createErrorLabelConstraints(i);
            labelFieldPanel.add(errorLabel, gbc);

            // add blank JLabel at the 0 position
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            labelFieldPanel.add(new JLabel(), gbc); 
        }

        JButton acceptButton = new JButton("Accept");
        acceptButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        acceptButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < LABELS.length - 1; i++) {
                String text = LABELS[i];
                JTextField textField = labelFieldMap.get(text);
                JLabel errorLabel = errorLabelMap.get(text);
                if (textField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    errorLabel.setText(ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    errorLabel.setText(" ");
                    System.out.println(text + " " + textField.getText());
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        });
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.setOpaque(false);
        btnPanel.add(acceptButton);        

        add(labelFieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createErrorLabelConstraints(int i) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2 * i + 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        return gbc;
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createTextFieldConstraints(int i) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2 * i;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        return gbc;
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createLabelConstraint(int i) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2 * i;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        return gbc;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyPanel mainPanel = new MyPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Resulting GUI:

[image]   [image]

Comment: A Swing expert told me today "Nah, Swing is dead . .  .    I strongly urge the OP to avoid this Java dead-end . . ." [:-)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: LOL, true, but if the question has reasonable code... ;)

Comment: Haha I am well aware. Unfortunately the target PC is too low end to run JavaFX without overbearing the CPU.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The issue seems to be coming from the line border part... When I remove the red border from being used, it doesn't resize the text boxes.

Comment: @Tacitus86: so set the background of the JTextField pink or wrap it in a compound border, the outer being your own border that you change, or use some other mechanism for marking bad data entry